# How should I organise support methods?

Tags: android

I have a bunch of small support methods in Android Studio I use as shortcuts in my development process, whether it's logging or popping up a toast. Where should I put these 'misc' methods? What is best practice?

At the moment they are seperate classes e.g

```
public class Message {
public static void message(Context context, String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Is it good to have a public 'SupportClass' filled with these methods or is this whole approach bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the developers place such methods in a class named `Utils` but there is neither a rule nor a convention for this.

This is not a bad practice. But if your helper class contains a lot methods, you can split up the class into other multiple classes for better maintainability.

Comment: Great, so it's not bad practice at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is Create multiple helpers in a package called helpers

Something like LogHelper , StringHelper , DateHelper...

you should declare those classes final and add a private Constructor, like this

```
public final class StringHelper {

    private StringHelper () {
        //Private constructor for avoiding this class to be construct
    }

      //... ( your public static methods goes here )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of grouping them together like this